# SIPml5 one sided voice

Tags: sip, webrtc, sipml

Below is the code of my dialer. I can register and connect calls successfully with the below code. But, after call is connected only the other end (non sipml5)  can hear voice. But, the sipml5 side can not hear anything.However, I could connect and pass voice using the sipml5 client from sipml5 website(sipml5.org/call.htm). I must be doing something wrong, but cant figure out what.

```
<script src="api/SIPml-api.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
        var readyCallback = function(e){
                createSipStack(); // see next section
            };
        var errorCallback = function(e){
                onsole.error('Failed to initialize the engine: ' + e.message);
            }
        SIPml.init(readyCallback, errorCallback);

        var sipStack;
        var callSession;

      function eventsListener(e){
          console.info('Change of status|Server response: '+e.type+':'+e.message+':'+e.
session+':'+e.description);       
           if(e.type == 'started'){
                    login();
                }
           else if(e.type == 'i_new_message'){ // incoming new SIP MESSAGE (SMS-like)
                acceptMessage(e);
            }
           else if(e.type == 'i_new_call'){ // incoming audio/video call
                if(confirm("Incomming Call Request! Do you accept?")){
                    acceptCall(e);   
                }else{
                    e.newSession.reject()
                }
            }
       else if(e.type == 'connected'){
           if(e.session == registerSession){
                setStatus(e.type,'Registered...');
           }else{
                setStatus(e.type,e.description);
           }
       }
       else if(e.type == 'i_ao_request' && e.description == 'Ringing' ){
                document.getElementById('call').value = 'End Call';
                setStatus(e.type,e.description);
            }
       else if(e.type == 'terminated' || e.type == 'terminating'){
           if(e.session == registerSession){
                setStatus('Unable to Register');
            }else{
                setStatus(e.type,e.description);
            } 
       }             
   }

   function createSipStack(){
            sipStack = new SIPml.Stack({
                    realm: 'foo.bar.com',
                    impi: 'usertest', 
                    impu: 'sip:usertest@foo.bar.com',
                    password: '1234',
                    display_name: 'alice',
                    websocket_proxy_url: 'ws://11.11.11.0:8080',
                    enable_rtcweb_breaker: false,
                    events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener },
                    sip_headers: [ // optional
                            { name: 'User-Agent', value: 'IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0' },
                            { name: 'Organization', value: 'SuperCops.us' }
                    ]
                }
            );
        }
   sipStack.start();


   function login(){
       registerSession = sipStack.newSession('register', {
                events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener } // optional: '*' means all events
       });
       registerSession.register();

   }
   function makeCall(){
       var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
       if(number == ''){
            alert('No number entered');
       }
       else if(document.getElementById('call').value == 'End Call'){
           callSession.hangup();
       }else{
           setStatus('Trying','Trying to call:'+numberFilter(number));
           callSession = sipStack.newSession('call-audio',{
               events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener }
           });
           callSession.call(numberFilter(number));
       }
   }

   function acceptCall(event){
        callSession = event.newSession;
        /*('accept',{
               events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener }
           });*/
        callSession.accept();
        eventsListener(callSession);
        setStatus('connected','In Call');
   }

   function setStatus(type,status){
       document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = status;
       if(type == 'terminated' || type == 'terminating'){
           document.getElementById('call').value = 'Call';
       }else if(status == 'Ringing' || status == 'Ringing' || status == 'In Call'  || type == 'Trying'){
           document.getElementById('call').value = 'End Call';
       }
   }     

   function numberFilter(number){
       return number;
   }
```

Comment: I guess you need specify `audio_remote` when new a `call-audio` session: `sipStack.newSession ('call-audio', {audio_remote: document.getElementById ('audio-remote'),  events_listener: { events: '*', listener: eventsListener }      });`